# INSTALLATION ENCOUNTER "WHITE SCREEN OF DEATH"

Tags: magento2, error, template, php-7

Why do some Magento 2 installations encounter "white screen of death" errors, where the site appears blank with no error messages displayed?**strong text**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

THE SOLOTION OF THE DEATH SCREEN ISUUE IS...
The "white screen of death" error in Magento 2 occurs when the site appears blank with no error messages displayed. There can be a number of reasons why this error occurs, and some of the most common causes include:

**`PHP memory limit:`** Magento 2 requires a certain amount of memory to function properly, and if the PHP memory limit is set too low, it can cause the site to crash and display a white screen. This can be resolved by increasing the PHP memory limit in the server configuration.

**`Plugin or theme conflict:`** Another common cause of the white screen of death is a conflict between plugins or themes installed on the site. This can happen when two or more plugins or themes try to modify the same files, causing a conflict. Disabling or removing the conflicting plugin or theme can help resolve the issue.

**`Corrupt core files:`** If the core files of Magento 2 are corrupted or missing, it can cause the white screen of death error. This can be resolved by reinstalling or upgrading Magento 2 to the latest version.

**`Database issues:`** If there are issues with the Magento 2 database, it can also cause the white screen of death error. This can happen when there is a problem with the database connection or when there is a conflict between different database tables. Resolving database issues requires expertise in MySQL and Magento 2.

**`Server issues:`** Sometimes, the white screen of death error can be caused by server issues, such as a misconfigured server or problems with server resources. Troubleshooting server issues requires expertise in server administration and web hosting.

Overall, troubleshooting the white screen of death error in Magento 2 can be a complex process that requires expertise in Magento 2, PHP, MySQL, and server administration. If you encounter this error, it's recommended to seek guidance from the Magento community or a certified Magento developer.